# Simply connected noncompact complete 2-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

Can a simply connected noncompact complete 2-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (endowed with the metric induced by the flat metric of $\mathbb{R}^3$ ) be conformally equivalent to the hyperbolic plane?

From the uniformization theorem I know that it must be conformmally equivalent either to the euclidean plane or to the hyperbolic plane. But can I exclude the second case?

Comment: To be clear, you mean an open simply-connected subset $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^2$ equipped with a complete Riemannian metric? Why is the half-plane model of the hyperbolic plane not an example?

Comment: Sorry! I meant $\R^3$!! I will edit the question! Thanks for the comment!

Comment: What about 2 sheeted hyperboloid?

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee But is one sheet of the hyperbolid (endowed with the metric induced by the ambient space) conformally equivalent to the hyperbolic plane? Observe that the metric on the submanifold comes from the flat metric of $\mathbb{R}^3$. I am not totally familiar with all the different models for hyperbolic geometr, so I don't know if this is true.

Comment: In the hyperboloid model of hyperbolic space, the metric on the hyperboloid is obtained by restricting the Lorentzian semi-metric $dx^2 + dy^2 - dz^2$, *not* by restricting the Euclidean metric $dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$. So the hyperboloid is not a good guess, and I'm pretty sure it is conformally Euclidean with the restricted Euclidean metric.

Comment: In fact the hyperboloid is asymptotic to the cone $x^2+y^2=z^2$, from which it follows that the restricted Euclidean metric on the hyperboloid is asymptotically flat, meaning that its Gaussian curvature converges uniformly to $0$ as one approaches infinity. I am pretty sure (but not entirely sure) that an asymptotically flat complete Riemannian metric on a surface diffeomorphic to the plane must be conformally Euclidean.

Comment: And, by the way, the question should be rewritten to rule out counterexamples such as the simply connected, complete, *compact* 2-dimensional submanifold $S^2$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks a lot for the comment! I will edit the question immediately! I was of course thinking about *noncompact* simply connected complete 2-dimensional submanifolds.

Comment: @Onil90 look at this https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111101/surfaces-in-mathbb-r3-with-negative-curvature-bounded-away-from-zero

Comment: @LeeMosher: Asymptotically flat surfaces can be conformal to the hyperbolic plane. See my answer.

Comment: Ah hah, I always wondered about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question (going back to Loewner) was studied by various people, the first example, I think, is due to Robert Ossermann

R. Osserman, [A hyperbolic surface in 3-space](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1956-007-01/S0002-9939-1956-0076042-9/). 
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 7 (1956), 54–58.

He constructs such surfaces as graphs of certain functions $f: {\mathbb R}^2\to {\mathbb R}$. More examples were constructed in:

H. Huber Riemannsche Flächen von hyperbolischem Typus im euklidischen Raum. Math. Ann. 139  (1959) 140–146.

R.Jenkins, [On hyperbolic surfaces in three-dimensional Euclidean space](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.mmj/1028998507). 
Michigan Math. J. 8 (1961) 1–5.

and, presumably, other papers.

There is a related question of the conformal type of a complete simply-connected surface of negative curvature which is not bounded away from zero. Such surface can be either of hyperbolic or of parabolic type, it depends on the rate of decay of curvature at infinity. For instance, for rotationally-symmetric metrics, i.e. metrics of the form 
$$
dr^2+g(r)^2 d\theta^2
$$ 
the metric is conformal to the complex plane if and only if
$$
\int_1^\infty g^{-1}=\infty. 
$$

See:

J. Milnor, On deciding whether a surface is parabolic or hyperbolic. 
Amer. Math. Monthly 84 (1977), no. 1, 43–46.

Milnor further proves that if (for all large $r$) the curvature $K(r)=K(r,\theta)$ satisfies
$$
K(r)\ge −\frac{1}{r^2 \log(r)} 
$$
then the metric is conformal to the complex plane, while if $g$ is unbounded and (for large $r$) 
$$
K(r)\le −\frac{1+\epsilon}{r^2\log(r)}
$$
then the metric is conformal to the open unit disk.

Milnor's criterion was extended to arbitrary metrics by Peter Doyle in

P.Doyle, [On deciding whether a surface is parabolic or hyperbolic](https://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~doyle/docs/milnor/milnor.ps), 
Geometry of random motion, 41–48, Contemp. Math., 73, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1988.

He proved that a metric $dr^2 + g^2(r,\theta)d\theta^2$ on the plane (in the polar coordinates) is conformal to the unit disk if and only if

$$
\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta}{\int_1^\infty \frac{dr}{g}}<\infty. 
$$

Edit. In view of Milnor's theorem, an explicit example of a complete surface in $E^3$ conformal to the unit disk can be obtained as follows. Let $f(r), r\ge 0$, be a nonnegative function  which near zero equals $0$ and for $r\ge 1$ equals $r^\beta$, $\beta> 2$. Consider the surface of revolution $S\subset E^3$ which is the graph of the function 
$$(r,\theta)\mapsto z=f(r)$$
 (I am using cylindrical coordinates $(r,\theta, z)$ on ${\mathbb R}^3$.) Then the surface $S$ is complete and conformal to the open unit disk.