# Examples/characterizations of parabolic Riemannian manifolds that have infinite injectivity radius?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature, potential-theory

> We say that a Riemannian manifold $M$ is $ parabolic$ if the only positive superharmonic functions on $M$ are constants. Then what are some examples/characterizations of parabolic Riemannian manifolds that have infinite injectivity radius at each point on $M$, apart from $\Bbb R^2$ ?

My intuitions:
I think parabolicity is connected with non-negative sectional curvature whereas infinite injectivity radius is associated with non-positive sectional curvature. So are such manifolds necessarily flat or are there some interesting examples? Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2561435/simply-connected-noncompact-complete-2-dimensional-submanifold-of-mathbbr3/2564854#2564854).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Have you seen my definition of a parabolic manifold?

Comment: Yes, I did. Parabolicity (in your sense) is a conformal invariant.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Your answer seems to specialize for dim=2. Anyway, it would be nice if you write a concise answer addressing this question.

Comment: I will do some calculations and add an answer later. But my examples will be 2-dimensional.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks, it will be much appreciated!